# Sockets for T1 3v led?

Tags: led, connector, mount

This is more a 'presentation' and 'usablity' question.

Is it possible to get an array type socket, prewired and capable of accepting several small (T1 or T1-3/4) led?

Ideally, I am looking to create an array of several led where any led can be replaced easily (by pulling out old and pushing in new), ideally with a matching dome diffuser, and ideally wired in paralell.

Is such a thing available and if not, what are my best options?

The end result should ideally be a bit like the inners of a torch with several led, where each led is individually and easily replaceable by your 2yr old son, or 90 yr old great great grandmother.

Comment: female dupont connectors work under most circumstances, aside from vibration and moisture-heavy environments. you can get 2-pin connectors, or just use ribbon cable.

Comment: how closely are the LEDs packed together? ..... a 2yr old and a 90yr old may not have the fine motor skills to replace the LED ..... each LED needs to be built into a module ..... maybe a 2.5mm audio jack .... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#/media/File:Photo-audiojacks.jpg   ..........  or something that is magnetically held in

Comment: Unlikely to find a solution that fits your needs.  How many and what supply voltage?  Skills for polarity orientation are needed. Diffused White LEDs, you make,  with sandpaper.  Breadboards are the common solution, but header and IC sockets may be used but requires current limiting R's for arrays.

Comment: It sounds like @dan is on the right lines for what I will need, which brings me to a 2nd issue I have been having.  I haven't looked at electronic components since about 1985 so have no idea what to search (I keep getting domestic wiring options).  Does anyone know what the leads are called with 2 wires and a small connector at each end with simply 2 holes, often used to connect components within computers?

Comment: The end product might be quite expensive which is why changing leds is a requirement for the end consumer.  I am hoping to wire about 5 or 7 leds accross 2 or 3 circuits so a switch can control the number of led lit at any one time, but effectively all led will still be wired in paralel so 3v leds and a 3v supply (2xAA or 2xAAA batteries) would mean no resistors needed. If the bit I wanted isn't available, then I can revistit the defuser later

Comment: On a note of caution for any other non experts who may read this post, I saw a basic instructional on youtube, but Ohms law was misapplied!  Luckily as it was only 1 3v 20mA led and a 9v battery power source nobody was going to get hurt (though at the size of the resistor, I am somewhat surprised the led lit as all!). Beware of 'instructional' resources from non qualified people.  I'm not sure I would trust the guy who did that video to change the batteries in my TV remote!

Answer (score 2):

These are single T1 3/4 sockets.

[Straight thru hole mount](http://static.vcclite.com/pdf/PCV-220-vertical-board-mount-drawing.pdf)
[right angle thru hole mount](http://static.vcclite.com/pdf/PCH-175-right-angle-mount-drawing.pdf)

---

A socket like this will likely work.

[image]
PDF: [Datasheet](http://www.on-shore.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/SAXXX0X0.pdf)